# MobileFirst My migrated iOS project unresponsive if I extend WLAppDelegate, but not if I extend WLCordovaAppDelegate

Tags: ios, migration, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I've migrated 9 iOS Hybrid apps from MobileFirst 6.3 to MobileFirst 7.1 using MobileFirst Studio.  4 of the apps work fine.   But the other 5, the UI is unresponsive to clicks.  As part of the automated migration process, the headers of these 5 apps (only) were changed to reference the new WLAppDelegate interface.  Strangely I've noticed that if I switch my AppName.h file from extending WLAppDelegate back to extending the original WLCordovaAppDelegate everything works fine.  Why?  I'd love to move off this deprecated code to your new WLAppDelegate interface.

My header and .m file match the defaults generated by MobileFirst Studio 7.1 when you request a new iOS app so it must be something else.

Here's my non-working .h and .m file

```
//
//  MyAppDelegate.h
//
//

#import <IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.h>


@interface MyAppDelegate : WLAppDelegate <WLInitWebFrameworkDelegate> {

}

@end

//
//  MyAppDelegate.m
//  IssuesReturns
//
//
#import "IssuesReturns.h"
#import <IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.h>
#import "CDVMainViewController.h"

@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    BOOL result = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    // A root view controller must be created in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController* rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];     

    [self.window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [[WL sharedInstance] showSplashScreen];
    // By default splash screen will be automatically hidden once Worklight JavaScript framework is complete. 
    // To override this behaviour set autoHideSplash property in initOptions.js to false and use WL.App.hideSplashScreen() API.

    [[WL sharedInstance] initializeWebFrameworkWithDelegate:self];

    return result;
}

// This method is called after the WL web framework initialization is complete and web resources are ready to be used.
-(void)wlInitWebFrameworkDidCompleteWithResult:(WLWebFrameworkInitResult *)result
{
    if ([result statusCode] == WLWebFrameworkInitResultSuccess) {
        [self wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully];
    } else {
        [self wlInitDidFailWithResult:result];
    }
}

-(void)wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully
{


    UIViewController* rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;

    // Create a Cordova View Controller
    CDVMainViewController* cordovaViewController = [[CDVMainViewController alloc] init] ;

    cordovaViewController.startPage = [[WL sharedInstance] mainHtmlFilePath];

    // Adjust the Cordova view controller view frame to match its parent view bounds
    cordovaViewController.view.frame = rootViewController.view.bounds;

    // Display the Cordova view
    [rootViewController addChildViewController:cordovaViewController];  
    [rootViewController.view addSubview:cordovaViewController.view];
    [cordovaViewController didMoveToParentViewController:rootViewController];  
}

-(void)wlInitDidFailWithResult:(WLWebFrameworkInitResult *)result
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR"
                                                  message:[result message]
                                                  delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`WLCordovaAppDelegate` is a deprecated compatibility API to allow easier migration of pre v6.2 apps to 6.2+ apps. It can be used but the recommendation is to use `WLAppDelegate`.

Comment: Idan, the hang only occurs when I try and use WLAppDelegate.  The UI is totally unresponsive to clicks.  If I switch back to WLCordovaAppDelegate, I don't get any issues.  Any ideas?  Here's my .m code..

Comment: I went ahead and opened a PMR 51828,442,000 to track this issue.  I'm not blocked as I can just keep using the old trusty WLCordovaAppDelegate, but it would be good to resolve so I could migrate forward eventually.